# Google Earth Engine - Area is undefined to used in if

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, javascript, geometry, area

I'm having trouble getting my `if` to recognize the value of the area.

When utilize `.type` returned *undefined*

Code doesn't return response

I tried:
`ee.Number` `.float` `.int`

````
var ar1 = a1.area();
var ar2 = a2.area();

// Square km
var are1 = ee.Number(ar1).divide(1e6);
var are2 = ee.Number(ar2).divide(1e6);


var n = are2.divide(are1);

var getvalue = ui.Button({
  label: 'Get Values',
  onClick: function() {
            if (n >= 0.75){
                  print('Green Flag');  
                } 
                else
                if (n >= (0.50) ){
                      print('Yellow Flag');
                    } else
                      if (n >= 0.25){
                            print('Red Flag');
                          } else if (n >= 0.0)
                            {print('Critical');
                                }
  }});
  
print(getvalue);```

<https://code.earthengine.google.com/6b883106cff3cbb99b6879c1e9cf7050>
````

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky aspect of GEE, what you are doing is that you are mixing client-side objects (i.e. "pure" JavaScript language, in this case your "if" loop) with server-side objects (i.e. Earth Engine objects, in this case "n" since you calculated it using the "divide" function) (check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server))

A quick workaround is to write:

```
var n = are2.divide(are1).getInfo();
```

Or use `ee.Algorithms.If()` instead of your "if" loop.